# Can a discrimination act be a charge filed by a prosecutor?

Tags: united-states, discrimination, prosecutorial-discretion, sex-discrimination

Can a discrimination, e.g. based on gender, race or age, charge be filed by a prosecutor or a prosecutor's office in the US?

Comment: In what country?

Comment: @user6726: Thanks for the question. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Charge" conventionally refers to a formal accusation of an offense which leads to criminal prosecution. It is a prosecutor who would file such a charge. The next question is whether there are criminal offenses subsumed under the rubric of anti-discrimination laws. There are a lot of anti-discrimination laws: numerous types at the federal, state and municipal level and different domains of discrimination (employment, public accommodation, education, voting...). Anti-discrimination laws generally describe civil consequences resulting from impermissible discrimination, not criminal penalties. [52 USC 10308a](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/52/10308), part of the Voting Rights Act of 1965, provides criminal penalties for anyone who (attempts to)
deprive any person of any right secured by section 10301-10304 or 10306. 10301 is the provision that people cannot be denied the right to vote on the basis of race of color. That is an example of a form of discrimination that can result in criminal charges, which are filed by a prosecutor. There is a broad class of criminal laws, the [hate crime laws](https://www.justice.gov/crt/hate-crime-laws), for example  it a crime to (threaten to) use force to interfere with housing rights based on race, color, religion, sex, disability, familial status, or national origin: but not age (it would be a different, non-federal crime). In all of these cases, it not bare discrimination, but discrimination in committing a crime.

Civil actions based on violation of anti-discrimination laws are often undertaken by the city attorney, attorney general of a state, or US Department of Justice. They may have various names such as "District Attorney", "State's Attorney", "County Prosecutor", and there isn't a strict segregation between the attorneys who prosecute criminal cases for the government and those who do other kinds of legal work. So a prosecutor would be the lawyer who files a discrimination action against someone.

Comment: 1. With regard to you last paragraph, are you saying a prosecutor whose position is a government job is permitted to do other legal work than prosecuting a crime. Does that legal work have to be for the government or is it allowed to be for private business?
2. Are you saying a hate crime based on race or gender is committed, it can be filed by a prosecutor since it is a crime as opposed to a civil tort?

Comment: Yes, and whether an attorney can both prosecute for the government and have a private practice depends on the laws of the jurisdiction. E.g. in Washington there are county-population laws for prosecuting attorneys and deputy prosecutors allowing part-time prosecutors for small counties.

Comment: What about question 2., where the prosecutor acting truly for the government?

Comment: More specifically w.r.t. 2, it can only be filed by a prosecutor.

Comment: Would you like to chime in on the question https://law.stackexchange.com/q/52587/17620?